# With Spring Data REST, why is the @Version property becoming an ETag and not included in the representation?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

In Spring Data REST (via Spring Boot 1.3.3), when I `GET` a resource collection of, say, `people`, the `@Version` property is not included with the resources:

```
$curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/people/1
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/people/1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.42.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< ETag: "0"
< Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 00:08:12 GMT
< Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 00:12:56 GMT
< 
{
  "id" : 1,
  "createdDate" : {
    "nano" : 351000000,
    "epochSecond" : 1461629292
  },
  "lastModifiedDate" : {
    "nano" : 351000000,
    "epochSecond" : 1461629292
  },
  "firstName" : "Bilbo",
  "lastName" : "Baggins",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/people/1"
    },
    "person" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/people/1"
    }
  }
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

by default, or when I configure my Spring Data repository:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationRepositoryConfiguration 
    extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration 
{    
    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(
        RepositoryRestConfiguration config
        ) 
    {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Person.class);
        config.setBasePath("/api/");
    }
}
```

The `@Version` is the version of the row of data which is incremented on updates, and included in the `ETag` *HTTP Header* data when I query a specific resource. Instead of having to invoke a `GET` on each resource in the collection, I'd prefer getting the `@Version` in the collection `GET` so I can write my application to check the `@Version` value on each resource update **without** performing the **`n`** addition `GET` round-trips.

Is there a way to include the `@Version` field in each of the resources a collection `GET`?

The entity definition looks like this:

```
@Data @Entity @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Instant createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;

    @Version
    @JsonProperty
    private Long version;

    …
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, there is not. The ETag is the HTTP equivalent to what's expressed as `@Value` property in the backend. Spring Data REST turns all backend related properties that have a corresponding mechanism in the HTTP protocol into exactly those: ids become URIs (and shouldn't be part of the payload either), `@LastModifiedDate` properties become headers, `@Version` properties, become ETags.

The reason is pretty simple: if you use HTTP, use the protocol means that are available to you to achieve things that are implemented on the data access level. That's one aspect in which Spring Data REST is *not* simply exposing a database to the web but actually inspects your model and translates model characteristics into protocol specific means.

Long story short: with Spring Data REST you have two options for updates:

1. Just `PUT` without an `If-Match` header — enforces overriding whatever is present on the server as the aggregate gets loaded, incoming data mapped onto it and it written back. You still get optimistic locking applied if another client changed the aggregate in the meantime (although an admittedly very short window). If that's the case you'll see a `409 Conflict`.
2. `PUT` with an `If-Match` header - Spring Data REST checks the ETag submitted against the current value of the version property of the aggregate and return a `412 Precondition Failed` in case there's a mismatch at that point. In that case clients can lookup the current state of the resource and decide how to proceed. They might just decide to override what's on the server using `PUT` without an `If-Match` header.

Similar optimizations can made for GET requests:

1. `GET` with `If-None-Match` (ETag) / `If-Modified-Since` (with Last-Modified header value) — You'll see a `304 Not Modified` in case the resource is still in the same state as before and you thus avoid spending bandwidth for the response.
2. Plain `GET` will always return the representation.

Comment: Thanks for the optimizations, @Oliver Gierke -- I'll play around with that a bit.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/ explores conditional PUTs and GETs in more details as well.

Comment: Yes, @gregturn -- that's where my question came from. :-)

Comment: Hi @Oliver Gierke, I am using 1. as you described to do PUT for my Spring-data-rest web app, but always got 409 conflict. And the expcetion is E11000 duplicate key error. I have post my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024658/e11000-duplicate-key-error-when-doing-put-for-modifiable-resource-with-spring-da?noredirect=1#comment61611829_37024658) Thanks.

Comment: I am wondering if it is okay to use ETags along with mentioned above headers for PATCH requests. Does Spring Data Rest gonna work?

Answer (score 2):

I believe not including the version in the body is a mistake, as we often pull a page of resources, so there we can't rely on the ETag. At least it should be configurable which it is not currently.

I simply add another function to the entity that exposes the version, I am on Spring Boot 2.4.4:

```
  // ...

  @Version
  private Long version;

  public Long getCurrentVersion() {
    return version;
  }

  // ...
```