# Spring Data REST, how to handle @Version property in listings

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.6 and Spring Data REST. I'm aware of thi discussion: [With Spring Data REST, why is the @Version property becoming an ETag and not included in the representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853343/with-spring-data-rest-why-is-the-version-property-becoming-an-etag-and-not-inc)

It's clear why SDR translate the @Version property into an Etag....but what about this quite common case: I've a list of entities (I get data using a `GET`) and I want do a logic delete of one of them. 
So I'll do a `PATCH` on that specific entity. In order to do the PATCH I need to set the `If-None-Match` header and therefore I need to know the version.

In this case so I fetched my list with a `GET`, but to make a `PATCH` of the object just to change the boolean property I've to fetch the entire object just to get the version.
Is it convenient? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.  I believe Spring/REST should return it in the entity body as a first class attribute, but REST has confused two different concerns: entity versioning, and HTTP messaging.  The solution is to expose a new "phantom" property that just happens to hold the object version:

```java
@Version
private int version; // the entity version, managed by JPA

public int getVersion() { return this.version; } // Spring suppresses this
public int getVisibleVersion() { return this.version; } // appears in entity JSON as "visibleVersion"
```